# xlx/xlxs file and AWS glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

New to AWS. Will spreadsheet xlx/xlxs files with multiple sheets work on AWS glue?

I am trying to set up an s3 dump for customers and files will be in a form of spreadsheet with multiple tabs.

Comment: Is your use case using data so large that it will exceed Lambda time of 15 mins? You can easily perform this use case using Lambda and AWS SDKs.

Comment: @smac2020 thank you for answering!  i am unfamiliar with how Lambda works. Can I  use Glue for this though? and what if i have millions of rows, what would be the best thing to do ?

Comment: Given that you have millions of rows - I suspect that it would exceed Lambda time limit. Glue logic uses Python so you would need to use a Python lib to work with these excel files.

Comment: this will point you in right direction -- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-version2-external-python-libraries/

Comment: I don't think you even need to add additional Python libraries for this to work, Glue already has some libraries included, such as `pandas`, that can read Excel files: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html#glue20-modules-provided